# Adding a field to an Azure SQL Server table

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a SQL Server database in Azure.  I need to add a field to one of the tables.  I have no idea how to proceed.  I'm very familiar with SQL Server but not on Azure.  Help!!!

Comment: Have you looked up `ALTER TABLE` ?

Answer (score 1):

You do it [**exactly** the same way as in SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190238.aspx).

```
ALTER TABLE ... ADD ...
```

or using Management Studio. If is recent enough, it can connect to Azure SQL DB.